# Supposed variable cannot be resolved as variable?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop

I'm doing a basic Java tutorial and below is the question.

Write a method that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print ÒFizzÓ instead of the number,and for the multiples of five print ÒBuzzÓ. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print ÒFizzBuzzÓ."

My code is below

```
public static void fizzBuzz(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 101; i= i +1 )
            System.out.println(i);
        if (i%3 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒFizzÓ");
        }else if (i % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒBuzzÓ");
        }else if (i % 15 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒFizzBuzzÓ");
        }
    }
```

Eclipse tells me that "i" cannot be resolved as a variable. This is confusing to me as I thought I already defined "i" as an integer in my for loop? Thanks for taking the time to solve this newbie question :)

Comment: Are your `if-else-if` meant to be within the `for` loop?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis seeing that he uses `i` in the conditions, I would say yes

Comment: @Dici seeing that Sotirios probably knows full well that they are, I would say that is a rhetorical question :P

Comment: @Amadan haha you're right

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes they are meant for the `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

Add braces or your loop body ends after the first statement. Also, for your approach you need to test 15 first because it's a multiple of 3 and 5

```
for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++) { // <-- i++ is short for i = i + 1
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i % 15 == 0) {
        System.out.println("ÒFizzBuzzÓ");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("ÒBuzzÓ");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("ÒFizzÓ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know a funny story about Apple who lost a few million dollars because a developer updated a code with an `if` block but... the `if` statement had only one instruction and no curly brackets and he did not see it. Thus, the code he was willing to add when the condition was met were actually ALWAYS executed.

In your case, you won't lose money but you surely did the same mistake :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 101; i= i +1 ) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i % 15 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒFizzBuzzÓ");
    } else if (i%3 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒFizzÓ");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒBuzzÓ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The last test will never run since 15 is `3 * 5`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that's right, thanks. Actually, I did not pay attention to the logic as the bracket problem was obvious

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually I ran the code with both your answers and got the same results, where the code did indeed run with both Fizz and Buzz in them. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

When Java says something cannot be resolved as a variable, it is usually been used outside the scope it was declared or it was not declared at all.In your case, your braceless for-loop is causing the problem.